# Unsupported class version error in java?

Tags: java, android, java-server

I'm trying to pass some response parameters using Android to a java web application. I'm using jdk 1.6_32 for android development and jdk1.5_06 on server side. Parameters which I'm trying to pass are login credentials(String) and png file which is Base64 encoded to string. Login credentials are being passed correctly but, when png file is being passed, server is throwing following exception:

```
15:08:33,264 ERROR [[ImageRetrieve]] Servlet.service() for servlet ImageRetrieve threw exception
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1629)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:850)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1299)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1181)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
    at com.apd.test.ImageRetrieve.doPost(ImageRetrieve.java:46)
    at com.apd.test.ImageRetrieve.doGet(ImageRetrieve.java:37)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:697)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.CustomPrincipalValve.invoke(CustomPrincipalValve.java:39)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:153)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

I'm unable to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are using some class that was compiled with JDK6 on the server (which runs on JDK5). All classes on the server must be compiled against JDK5 for your setup to work correctly.

Comment: I cleared the class files and made sure that they were compiled on JDK5, still facing the same exception..

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are running the server with an older JDK than the one you used to compile the classes. That's what the error message is telling you.

Comment: I'm using jar for Base64... it might be compiled in higher version of JDK...it might be the issue..